# How to match for multiple patterns in the specific column?

Tags: bash, unix, awk, grep, pattern-matching

I was wondering if there would be a more efficient way to use awk/grep/sed to solve the following problem?

I would like parse through a certain column of my input file (in this example column 1) and use awk/grep/any other function to subset and select patterns that match my query. For example given the file below ;

```
chr1    3009844 3009908 DXX 42  -
chr2    3000386 3000450 DXX 15  -
chr3    3000386 3000450 DXX 15  -
chr4    3000386 3000450 DXX 15  -
chr5    3000386 3000450 DXX 15  -
chr6    3000386 3000450 DXX 15  -
chr7    3000386 3000450 DXX 15  -
chr8    3000386 3000450 DXX 15  -
chr9    3000386 3000450 DXX 15  -
chr10   3000386 3000450 DXX 15  -
chr11   3000386 3000450 DXX 15  -
chr12   3000386 3000450 DXX 15  -
chr13   3000386 3000450 DXX 15  -
chr14   3000386 3000450 DXX 15  -
chr15   3000386 3000450 DXX 15  -
chr16   3000386 3000450 DXX 15  -
chr17   3000386 3000450 DXX 15  -
chr18   3000386 3000450 DXX 15  -
chr19   3000386 3000450 DXX 15  -
chrX    3000386 3000450 DXX 15  -
chrY    3000386 3000450 DXX 15  -
chr1_GL456210_random    3000386 3000450 DXX 15  -
chr1_GL456211_random    3000386 3000450 DXX 15  -
chr1_GL456212_random    3000386 3000450 DXX 15  -
chr1_GL456221_random    3000386 3000450 DXX 15  -
chr4_GL456216_random    3000386 3000450 DXX 15  -
chr4_JH584292_random    3000386 3000450 DXX 15  -
chr4_JH584295_random    3000386 3000450 DXX 15  -
chr5_GL456354_random    3000386 3000450 DXX 15  -
chr5_JH584296_random    3000386 3000450 DXX 15  -
chr5_JH584297_random    3000386 3000450 DXX 15  -
chr5_JH584299_random    3000386 3000450 DXX 15  -
chrX_GL456233_random    3000386 3000450 DXX 15  -
```

I would just like to have an output which only has chr1-chr22, chrX and chrY present in the first column, for instance ;

```
chr1    3009844 3009908 DXX 42  -
chr2    3000386 3000450 DXX 15  -
chr3    3000386 3000450 DXX 15  -
chr4    3000386 3000450 DXX 15  -
chr5    3000386 3000450 DXX 15  -
chr6    3000386 3000450 DXX 15  -
chr7    3000386 3000450 DXX 15  -
chr8    3000386 3000450 DXX 15  -
chr9    3000386 3000450 DXX 15  -
chr10   3000386 3000450 DXX 15  -
chr11   3000386 3000450 DXX 15  -
chr12   3000386 3000450 DXX 15  -
chr13   3000386 3000450 DXX 15  -
chr14   3000386 3000450 DXX 15  -
chr15   3000386 3000450 DXX 15  -
chr16   3000386 3000450 DXX 15  -
chr17   3000386 3000450 DXX 15  -
chr18   3000386 3000450 DXX 15  -
chr19   3000386 3000450 DXX 15  -
chrX    3000386 3000450 DXX 15  -
chrY    3000386 3000450 DXX 15  -
```

I managed to find the solution using the command below:

```
awk '$1 == "chr1" || $1 == "chr2" || $1 == "chr3" || $1 == "chr4" || $1 == "chr5" || $1 == "chr6" || $1 == "chr7" || $1 == "chr8" || $1 == "chr9" || $1 == "chr10" || $1 == "chr11" || $1 == "chr12" || $1 == "chr13" || $1 == "chr14" || $1 == "chr15" || $1 == "chr16" || $1 == "chr17" || $1 == "chr18" || $1 == "chr19" || $1 == "chr20" || $1 == "chrX" || $1 == "chrY"'  in_file > out_file
```

It works fine but was wondering if dear members would have a more elegant way to solve the problem? Or if you could point to resource to explore awk/grep in linux it would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a regular expression:

```
awk '$1 ~ /^chr(1?[0-9]|2[0-2]|X|Y)$/' file
```

This uses `$1 ~ /^pattern$/` to chose the good lines consisting in exactly `pattern` (note `^` for beginning and `$` for end).

The pattern is on the form `chr(..|..|..)`, meaning: match `chr` followed by either of the `|`-separated conditions within `()`.

These conditions can be either of:

- a number (possible 1 followed by a digit) (`1?[0-9]`)
- a number being 2 + any of 0, 1, 2 (`2[0-2]`)
- X
- Y

Demo automatically explained: https://regex101.com/r/gH1kS4/2

Comment: this would also match `chr0`. If this is not intended, we can refactor a little bit.

Comment: @BlueMoon true! Did not check the full explanation but just the sample input / desired output. Updated, thanks.

Comment: Very Cool! If i understand the code $1- specific the 1st column. "~" ?? What is the function of "~"? . And I have no idea what "1?" is doing.. Would you mind elaborating a bit? :)

Comment: @Learner Yes, `field ~ /pattern/` is the way to perform a regular expression on a field content. `1?` is a regex meaning: 1 can appear one time or not, so it makes it optional. See my updated answer.

Comment: Got it, i'l read a bit more on regular expression and awk. Thanks so much for the explanation!

Comment: @Learner you can get it explained automatically here: https://regex101.com/r/gH1kS4/2

Answer (score 2):

If you want something easier to maintain (e.g. editing or adding new lines/patterns to match) and also something easier to understand, especially if you just started engaging with regular expressions, use the `grep -f match.list input.txt` format:

Create a file with the patterns you want to match (`match.list`):

```
^chr[1-9][[:space:]]\|      # this matches chr1-chr9
^chr1[0-9][[:space:]]\|     # this matches chr10-chr19
^chr2[12][[:space:]]\|      # this matches chr21-22
^chr[XY][[:space:]]\|       # this matches chrX and chrY
new_string_or_pattern\|     # ... your new pattern ...
```

Then just call `grep` like this:

```
grep -f match.list input.txt
```

As you can see above, you can even add comments to the list of patterns, using the `\|` trick (ending each pattern with `\|`), so you can remember what you did yesterday or where did you find the regex. And you may add new fixed strings or patterns by just adding new lines. Also, if you find it difficult to create a complex regex, you may just create a pattern file with the fixed strings you want to match:

```
^chrX
^chrY
...
```

Another benefit of this approach is that you may maintain several pattern files, representing different sub-queries you may need to run daily. E.g.

```
grep -f chromosomes_n input.txt
grep -f chromosomes_xy input.txt
grep -f chromosomes_random input.txt
```

The only drawback of the approach is that `grep` will get slower if you add more than a dozen patterns in each file. But that will be a problem only if your input file has hundreds of thousands of lines.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this simplified regex with `grep`:

```
grep "^chr\(1\?[0-9]\|2[012]\|[XY]\)[[:space:]]" filename
```

The logic is contained within the parentheses `\(..\)`

- `1\?[0-9]` - match 0-9 optionally preceded by 1
- `2[012]` - match 2 followed by 0, 1 or 2
- `[XY]` - match X or Y

Comment: Thanks a lot :) so elegant!! :) Is there a place in the ice that specifies we are only searching the 1st column? And YOU ARE A GENOUS! :)

Comment: @Learner the anchor `^` in the regex means we will always start the match from the *beginning* of the line, but it's not really "column" aware. The other answer using awk's `$1` will operate on the first field, which is whitespace delimited by default

Answer (score 0):

Given your posted example all you need to get the output you want is either of these (or other simple REs):

```
awk '$1 !~ /_/' file
awk '$1 ~ /^[[:alnum:]]+$/' file
```

so you MAY not have to list specific "patterns" at all depending on your real world requirements.

Answer (score -1):

Below will do the work.

```
grep -v -w 'random'
```